# Is it considered bad form to call `next` on the input sequence of a list comprehension?

Tags: python, coding-style, python-3.x

I want to extract lines from a stream that are preceded by the character `L`. The list comprehension below does the job, but calls `next` on the stream inside the comprehension in a way I've never seen before. Is it considered bad form?

```
clauses = [
    list(map(int, next(stream)))
    for line in stream
    if line == 'L'
]
```

The `next` advances the sequence so that lines following `L` lines never pass through the predicate, which violates the "never modify a sequence you're iterating on" principle. But I wonder if this case could be an exception...

Comment: And what happens, when your stream only contains `L` or the last thing in your stream is `L`? On the first look it really looks nice, but it is perhaps too clever.

Comment: It would be more understandable IMO to just iterate in pairs of lines so you have e.g. `[[int(char) for char in next_] for current, next_ in ... if current == 'L']`.

Comment: @thomasjunk Right, you have to catch StopIteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Python's Zen - explicit is better than implicit. Using `next()` in the generator expression does not feel good. What about your own generator with all the logic in the open:

```
def take_one_after(iterable, sentinel):
    take = False
    for item in iterable:
        if item == sentinel:
            take = True
        elif take:
            take = False
            yield item


print(list(take_one_after(stream, 'L')))
```

(Note, I do not do anything with `int`, etc)

Also, `itertools` module may be helpful if you want one-liner (eg, using `tee` to duplicate stream into two, consume one item on second stream, then `zip` both streams into tuples and readily take tuple's send element when first one is `'L'` - this is what qualifies as iterating in pairs of lines as per jonrsharpe comment, but the code may be too cryptic).

Iterators can be chained for any kind of processing and turned into lists only at the end of processing.

Comment: Hm, your answer mutates state, though, which is something I try to avoid...

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean by that. The stream is of course consumed (as it is in your example). What state it mutates?

Comment: I mean mutating the variable take; I would instead do for line in stream: if line == 'L': try: yield next(stream) catch StopIteration: pass

Comment: Not sure why it is important to you: It's a local variable in the closure. If so, please, state in the question you are trying to achieve purely functional solution.

Comment: Ya, I guess I should have stated that preference. It's not really a hard requirement for me.